# Number of threads in thread pool for good perfomance

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a `Executor` thread pool with core size and maximum size both kept at 40 and each thread will use a HTTP connection from `PoolingClientConnectionManager` of Apache HTTP client with 40 connections per host route. I can see that if load is less the performance is also coming less...can you guys please help me out?

Comment: I don't see how. Your capacity and your requirements are only known to you. Try increasing and decreasing things until you get what you need.

Comment: Experimentation is the best way, because each app profile is different. The typical starting point is the number of processor cores + 2

Answer (score 0):

Use something like following:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

service.execute(someRunnable);
```

In this case, you needn't worry about the number of threads that are running.
The system will automatically scale the number of threads up and down for you.

Here is the documentation:

> public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool()
>
> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will
>   reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These
>   pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute
>   many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse
>   previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is
>   available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads
>   that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed
>   from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will
>   not consume any resources. Note that pools with similar properties but
>   different details (for example, timeout parameters) may be created
>   using ThreadPoolExecutor constructors.
>
> Returns: the newly created thread pool

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how many cores you have in the host that's running your JVM and how much CPU you expect each thread to utilise.

Assuming an 8 core host where *nothing* else was running aside from your JVM, every task you execute is purely CPU bound, then you'd probably want to have a thread pool size of 7 (leaving one core free for JVM activities like garbage collection and other OS tasks).

However, systems are never that predictable, so it's probably better to do some profiling under expected loads and seeing what works best.

Comment: that would be the case for non-blocking i/o, but blocking connections can often get blocked in an i/o operation effectively making no use of CPU, so generally with blocking i/o one would want more worker threads than CPU cores

Comment: That's why I mentioned 'purely CPU bound'.  I guess I should have been explicit about how you should increase the thread count for tasks that are not purely CPU bound.